# function file_get_contents not always working

Tags: php

for some reason, if I try to download this image below, I get this error. Every 1 of 2 images are returning this error.. any pointer ?

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.ndcontent.com/rk/mikesapartment/faces/marica.jpg ) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in C:\xampp\htdocs\tgp\index.php on line 22
```

The code I use is :  ($rand is a 16 digit int. who changes on every download)

```
file_put_contents('img/'.$rand.'.jpg', file_get_contents($img_url));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your URL ends with a whitespace

```
(http://www.ndcontent.com/rk/mikesapartment/faces/marica.jpg )
                                                            ^
```

which results in a 404 Not Found error.

Solution: [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) the URL first